# In XCode 4.2, can't set get-task-allow. Also do not exist option for create the Entitlements file

Tags: xcode4, entitlements

I need to build a adhoc release.

I have Xcode 4.2. Under File/New, do not exist a option for a new Entitlements file.

Under the project settings, say "Enable Entitlements". It create the file, but have no the keys of the old Entitlements. If I put the get-task-allow  manually, this have not effect at all...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the entitlement file for ad hoc testing (i.e. distribution the ".ipa" file)
on your testing device, then the following can help.

1. in Xcode 4.2, the entitlement file is not needed (is not used, Xcode will do the work)
2. delete the references to entitlement file from the Build Setting (both project and target)
3. set the code sign identity to ad hoc ( Phone distribution} profile in the Build Setting (both project and target) configuration
4. Using Product->Edit Scheme menu, set the Archive to your ad hoc configuration
5. Clean and Archive, this will build the ipa file into Xcode organizer
6. Organizer > Share ... sign the code with your ad hoc (Phone distribution) profile
7. Save the ipa file where you need it
8. drag the ipa file into iTunes
9. sync your devices